# What is "ForceSecureCompartment" is rasdial/rasphone?

Tags: windows, vpn

I'm editing the configuration of a VPN manually on Windows 11 by editing "rasphone.pbk", and I noticed there is a config `ForceSecureCompartment=0`. Just out of curiosity, can anyone explain what this does? I've googled around looking for documentation but haven't found anything.